# python 2.7 regular expression match with \r\n in string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Wondering if any ways to match string contains `\r \n`? It seems the same regular expression match does not work if input string content contains `\r \n`. Using Python 2.7.

**works pretty good**,

```
import re

content = '{(1) hello (1)}'
reg = '{\(1\)(.*?)\(1\)}'
results = re.findall(reg, content)

print results[0]

prog = re.compile(reg)
results = prog.findall(content)

print results[0]
```

**will not work when add `\r \n`**

```
import re

content = '{(1) hello \r\n (1)}'
reg = '{\(1\)(.*?)\(1\)}'
results = re.findall(reg, content)

print results[0]

prog = re.compile(reg)
results = prog.findall(content)

print results[0]
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: Briefly: escape the backslashes or use raw strings.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 .. This is related to capturing white spaces..am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> content = '{(1) hello \r\n (1)}'
>>> reg = '{\(1\)(.*?)\(1\)}'
>>> results = re.findall(reg, content, re.DOTALL)
>>> 
>>> print results[0]
 hello 

>>> 
>>> prog = re.compile(reg, re.DOTALL)
>>> results = prog.findall(content)
>>> 
>>> print results[0]
 hello 

>>>
```

From [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> '.' (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a
>   newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any
>   character including a newline.

Comment: Nice, Nehal, vote up. Will try and if no issues, will mark your reply as answer.